# Do something once click count reaches X

Tags: javascript, count, onclick

I have a basic click counter (desc) which works fine but how do you make it do something once it once it reaches X?

JS:

```
var clicks = 20;
 function clicker() {
   clicks--;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onClick="clicker()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">20</a></p>
```

I've tried if statement inside and outside of the function but it didn't work:

```
if (clicks == 10) {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "finished";
}
```

Comment: What does `d` stand for ? document ?

Comment: Sorry yes document, I will amend post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to select an element with an id of `p`, which doesn't exist in the code you've given us. I believe you were trying to select the `p` element, in which case you could either use `document.querySelector('p')` or `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]`.

Note, that both of these will select the first `p` element in the document, which is probably not what you want. You'd have to have a more specific identifier, like a class or an ID.

Note that with `document.querySelector('...')`, you can use CSS-style selectors, so select an ID with `#id`.

```js
var clicks = 20;

function clicker() {
  clicks--;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

  if (clicks == 10) {
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = "finished";
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="clicker()">Click me</button>
<p>
  Clicks: <a id="clicks">20</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, p element is fine to use (in this instance) as there is only one instance of p.

Answer (score 1):

have you had the element id of "p"? I think it would be easier if you do that with ASCENDING method.

Comment: I didn't notice i had `byid` rather than `TagName`, rushing things i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicks = 20;
 function clicker() {
   clicks--;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    if(clicks == 0) {
        //Do your stuff
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:return clicker();">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">20</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a hook. Pass a function to the clicker which is called every time, which will do the logic

```js
var clicks = 20;

function clicker(doSomething) {
  clicks--;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  if(doSomething !== undefined) doSomething()
}

function doSomething() {
  if (clicks == 10) {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "finished";
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="clicker(doSomething)">Click me</button>
<p id="p">Clicks: <a id="clicks">20</a>
</p>
```